# Vis.js - Only show finished network diagram, no animation, no interaction

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am a little bit struggling on how to use **Vis.js** to only show the **final** result of a **stabilized graph**, without any stabilization animation or interaction possibilities.

Is there someone that could push me to the correct direction?

If I disable physics completely, the graph shows all nodes one overlaying the other naturally.

Thank you already!

---

**EDIT**

Here is the code that I have for the options:

```
Stabilization stabilization = new Stabilization();
stabilization.setFit(true);

BarnesHut barnesHut = new BarnesHut();
barnesHut.setGravitationalConstant(-23000);
barnesHut.setCentralGravity(0);
barnesHut.setSpringLength(0);
barnesHut.setSpringConstant(0.5f);
barnesHut.setDamping(1);
barnesHut.setAvoidOverlap(1);

Physics physics = new Physics();
physics.setEnabled(true);
physics.setBarnesHut(barnesHut);
physics.setSolver(Physics.Solver.barnesHut);

Smooth smooth = new Smooth();
smooth.setEnabled(false);
smooth.setType(Smooth.Type.continuous);
smooth.setRoundness(0);

Edges edges = new Edges();
edges.setSmooth(smooth);

Interaction interaction = new Interaction();
interaction.setDragNodes(false);

Options options = new Options();
options.setPhysics(physics);
options.setEdges(edges);
options.setInteraction(interaction);
```

Please be aware that this code is used for a wrapper around vis.js, although the options should reflect the vis.js options.

So it is ok if the answer does not contain any Java code but the actual vis.js hints, I will map it to the wrapper implementation myself.

Comment: A sample/demo of your code of what you have already tried would be helpful.

Comment: The thing is that I am not directly using vis.js but in conjunction with a framework: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/visjs-addon , so I assume the code would not be useful here.

Comment: I believe this addon is just a wrapper to vis.js, right? If that's the case, adding the vis.js code you are using to your question will be useful.

Comment: As requested I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the animation is disabled by default, by having the [`stabilize`](https://github.com/sameeraroshan/visjs/blob/a1fe860c48b7ce04a5baeca59670494977617878/src/main/java/org/vaadin/visjs/networkDiagram/options/Options.java#L22) option set to true.

If you still see an animation, then try to increase the [`iterations`](https://github.com/sameeraroshan/visjs/blob/a1fe860c48b7ce04a5baeca59670494977617878/src/main/java/org/vaadin/visjs/networkDiagram/options/Options.java#L28) option, which is by default set to `1000`.

```
options.setStabilizationIterations(2000);
```

---

I have created a [simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjwg1jk5/2/) using the latest version of Vis.js (4.19). Bear in mind that the [VisJs-Addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/visjs-addon) uses an older verion of Vis.js (3.11).

Comment: It seems that this does not work with the addon. Setting the stabilize option to true still shows an animation at the beginning. I added a larger dataset to your fiddle. Also there sometimes it still wobbles and floats unfortunately: https://jsfiddle.net/cjwg1jk5/3/

Comment: I've noticed as well that sometimes it goes crazy. I have a feeling that it's a bug in Vis.js unfortunately. I have updated the fiddle with increased number of iterations. Have a look if it makes any difference: https://jsfiddle.net/cjwg1jk5/5/

Comment: came across the same issue, tried increasing the iterations, still the animation persist, any updates to the solution ?

Comment: Hey @TheViralGriffin did you solved it?